# Access the weight values of a polygon

Tags: python

How can I access the weight values of a polygon resp. it's vertices by the vertex group **name**?

```
ob = bpy.context.active_object
vertexGrp = ob.vertex_groups["Group1"]
for poly in ob.data.polygons:
  weight = 0                        
  for vert in poly.vertices:
      weight += ob.data.vertices[vert].groups[vertexGrp].weight

      # The commented lines didn't work either
      #weight += ob.data.vertices[vert].groups[1].weight
      #weight += ob.data.vertices[vert].groups["Group1"].weight

  #do something with the weight
```

It's about the last line, including the commented ones, that give me an error, it seems I don't use it right. Googled for hours, but didn't find an example I could understand. Please help.

Comment: related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/621/return-list-of-associated-vertex-index-weight-values-for-a-given-vertex-group?rq=1

Answer (score 5):

OP (me) didn't realise that a weight value of 0 auto-removes a vertex from the group. Also you need to use the index for accessing the weight data. So this works:

```
import bpy

ob = bpy.context.active_object
vertexGrp = ob.vertex_groups["Group"].index
for poly in ob.data.polygons:
    weight = 0    
    try:                    
        for vert in poly.vertices:           
            weight += ob.data.vertices[vert].groups[vertexGrp].weight
        weight /= len(poly.vertices)
        print(weight)
    except:
        print("no vgroup")
```